Local Network permission working on Debug but not on Release for iOS
I'm developing a MAUI .Net mobile app, which communicates to a desktop app over the local network. To do so, I need the local network permission request to pop when an operation tries to use the local network for the first time, and the permission to be shown in the app native settings.
As of now, the app works as intended in Debug but when I try to deploy on any physical iOS device, the permission is neither requested nor shown in the app settings.
My Info.plist:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to your camera to capture skin images that can be added to your patient’s record. These photos will only be transferred to the patient’s file at your request.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to your photos library to select skin images that can be added to your patient’s record. These photos will only be transferred to the patient’s file at your request.</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to microphone</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs the photo library to store pictures</string>
    <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs calendar permission but it does not access to your calendar data</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to your location to access your WiFi configuration and to notify you if WiFi is not properly enabled.</string>
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>fr</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to your local network to send data to the desktop app.</string>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/appicon.appiconset</string>
</dict>
</plist>

My MAUI project:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;</TargetFrameworks>

        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>DermAtoZ</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

        <!-- Display name -->

        <!-- App Identifier -->

        <!-- Authors -->
    
        <!-- Versions -->

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net8.0-ios'">
      <CodesignKey>Correct value</CodesignKey>
      <CodesignProvision>Correct value</CodesignProvision>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
      <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
      <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
      <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>False</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
      <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
      <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
      <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->

        <!-- Splash Screen -->

        <!-- Images -->

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
    </ItemGroup>

    
    <!-- Images -->

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Acr.UserDialogs" Version="9.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.3.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="ExifLibNet" Version="2.1.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="MetadataExtractor" Version="2.8.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Graphics" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp" Version="2.88.9" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="6.0.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Federation" Version="8.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="8.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="8.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="6.0.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Connectivity" Version="3.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Media" Version="6.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugins.Settings" Version="3.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Zeroconf" Version="3.6.11" />
        <PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls" Version="0.4.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Localization -->
    <!-- Compiled pages -->

</Project>


The functionality works or it throws error?
